# Opening and closing round brackets give continuous 0s or 9s in terminal without further keypress

Tags: rhel, keyboard

I have got assigned a new virtual machine at my company.

The issue I am facing is when I type `(` or `)` it prints `9` or `0` continuously after the bracket till we interrupt it. I couldn't find what command might be causing this.

Currently we are working on `csh` but this issue is present with `bash` as well.

What keyword should I be searching for finding the root cause of this?

eg:

```
(999999999999999999999999999999 )0000000000000000
                               ^                ^--------- manual Ctrl+C interrupt
                               |
                               |
                               |---------------------------manual Ctrl+C interrupt
```

Comment: what about the rest of the numbers

Comment: Rest has no issue

Comment: The parentheses are usually on the `9` and `0` keys (on a keyboard with US layout). Are you having issues with these keys getting stuck in general? What about the keys on either side (`*`/`8` and `{`/`[`)? Or any other key in combination with `Shift`?

Comment: Yes, US keyboard. I tried different US keyboard and it's not related to hardware.

Comment: What is type of VM are you running (e.g. VMware, VirtualBox etc.)?

Comment: Not sure. I just have virtual machine name and password and we login with that.

Comment: I found out that if I press shift a little bit longer this issue doesn't happen. No idea why?

Comment: Is this still an issue? If it was solved, consider adding a solution below in the answer box.

Comment: @Kusalananda: This issue happens when typing speed is fast. But not exactly sure why it happened. Those who type fast had this issue at my company. None was able to explain why. May be some keybinding thing.